# Why Is My Java Scheduler Is Not Working in AEM?

Tags: java, aem

I have written a Java scheduler for AEM. When I upload the jar file in Apache Felix at `system/console/bundle` my Java service is not started.

### My code:

```
@Component
@Service(value = Runnable.class)
@Properties(value = { @Property(name = "scheduler.period", longValue = 1),
        @Property(name = "scheduler.concurrent", boolValue = false), })
public class DisclosureLevel_Scheduler implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DisclosureLevel_Scheduler.class);

    @Reference
    private DisclosureLevelService disclosureLevelService;
    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            log.info("disclosureLevelService Job Started ::: ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in scedular job " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing is printed in my log file :(

Component service status is `unsatisfied reference`.

Comment: Can you please check if the Service and/or Component are `active`? You could also `grep` your error log for `DisclosureLevel_Scheduler` to find out if there were any issues with the service.

If I would to hazard a guess one of your `@References` can't be satisified. Probably the `DisclosureLevelService`. Therefore, the service is not started.

Since both referenced services are not used in your example remove them for the time being and see if your "scheduler" works.

Comment: its staus shows [unsatisfied] refernce

Comment: This `unsatisfied` reference is the reason your component/service does not start. Which of the two references is `unsatisfied`? Have you tried your example without the `@Reference`? Your `run` method does not need them (right now).

Comment: yes its worked :-)  without the @Reference thank you

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086794/do-i-need-any-more-changes-for-aem-schedulers) question, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

> Component service status is unsatisfied reference

That means that AEM is not able to "inject" one or both of your `@Reference` you defined in your class. This usually happens if the service that is supposed to be injected does not exist.

Looking at your references I think the `DisclosureLevelService` is missing, because `ResourceResolverFactory`is provided by AEM (or Sling for that matter) itself and should be there unless there is something really wrong with your AEM.

To check if your services exist, go to Felix console `<your-host>/system/console/services`. To check if the component exists go to Felix console `<your-host>/system/console/components`.