# Configuration changes for AEM Schedulers?

Tags: java, aem, scheduler

I am trying to implement simple scheduler for my project requirement, my project is using `Adobe AEM`. As of now  I gone through Adobe site and tried to implement the given examples provided but none of them updating my `error.log` file.

```
package sling.docu.examples;
import com.majesco.logger.service.impl.Logger;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import com.majesco.dcf.common.util.CommonConstants;
@Component
@Service(value = Runnable.class)
@Property( name = "scheduler.period", longValue = 10)
public class ScheduledPeriodicJob implements Runnable {
    Logger logger = new Logger().getInstance(CommonConstants.COMMONSERVICE_MODULE_ID);
    public void run() {
        logger.debug("#########################################");
        logger.debug("*****************************************");
        logger.debug("*****************************************");
        logger.debug("*****************************************");
        logger.debug("******** ScheduledPeriodicJob ***********");
        logger.debug("*****************************************");
        logger.debug("*****************************************");
        logger.debug("*****************************************");
        logger.debug("#########################################");
    }
}
```

So, according to [this](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scheduler-service-commons-scheduler.html#scheduling-at-periodic-times), it should work

`pom.xml` for dependancies

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.majesco</groupId>
        <artifactId>customerportal</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.majesco</groupId>
    <artifactId>commonservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>commonservice</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
            <version>3.8.1</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.majesco</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectmodel</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.majesco</groupId>
            <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Simple Json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate Core API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency> -->



        <!-- postgresql Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- EHCache Core APIs -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId> <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId> 
            <version>2.6.9</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- Hibernate EHCache API -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId> 
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- EHCache uses slf4j for logging -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId> 
            <version>1.7.5</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- @log4j2 xml dependency -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> 
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId> <version>2.0</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- javax.mail dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- slf4j-api dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- slf4j-simple dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- pgichecksum dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.billdesk.pgidsk</groupId>
            <artifactId>pgichecksum</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- esbservicesclient dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>esbservices_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbservicesclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- esbpolicysearchclient dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>esbpolicysearch_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbpolicysearchclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- esbcustomerserviceclient dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>esbcustomerservice_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbcustomerserviceclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- esbcustomerserviceclient dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>esbaccountservice_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbaccountserviceclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- esbgenericserviceclient dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>esbgenericservice_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbgenericserviceclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- esbgenericintegrationclient dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>genericintegration_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbgenericintegrationclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start pooja added 040817-->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>esbusermanagement_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbusermanagementclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End pooja added 040817-->

        <!-- Start pooja added 050917-->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>esbrenewalstatus_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbrenewalstatusclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End pooja added 050917-->


        <!-- updateCustomerService<07062018> dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>esbupdatecustomer_service</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbupdatecustomerservice</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- updateCustomerService<07062018> dependency -->

        <!-- esbdatabasefetchservice dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>esbdatabasefetchservice_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>esbdatabasefetchservice</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- esbdatabasefetchservice dependency -->



        <!-- base64 commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added for send email functionality -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- 1574973 start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>osgi.annotation</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>                
                <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>



<!-- 1574973 end -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <resources>
            <!-- standard Maven folder -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <!-- plus root folder -->
            <resource>
                <directory>.</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>plugin.xml</include>
                    <include>META-INF/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>

                <configuration>
                    <unpackBundle>true</unpackBundle>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <!-- <Export-Package>com.majesco.portal.service.*;version=${project.version}</Export-Package> -->
                        <!-- <Import-Package>*</Import-Package> -->
                        <!-- <Import-Package>!*</Import-Package> <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency> 
                            <Bundle-ClassPath>.</Bundle-ClassPath> -->
                        <!-- <Bundle-ActivationPolicy>lazy</Bundle-ActivationPolicy> -->
                        <!-- <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency> -->
                        <Embed-Dependency>!objectmodel,*</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Export-Package>com.majesco.dcf.common.*,com.majesco.dcf.pg.*,com.majesco.dcf.receipt.*,com.unotechsoft.stub.*,stub.unotechsoft.com.wsdl*,org.apache.http.impl.client*,org.apache.http.ssl*,org.apache.http*,org.apache*,org.datacontract.schemas*</Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework,org.hibernate.*,com.majesco.dcf.pa.json,org.json.*,*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
                        <!-- <Export-Package>${export.packages}</Export-Package> -->
                        <!-- <Export-Package>!com.majesco.service.activator,com.majesco.service.*;version=${project.version}</Export-Package> -->
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.majesco.dcf.common.service.activator.CommonServiceBundleActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                    <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                    <excludePackageNames>com.majesco.dcf.common.util*,com.majesco.dcf.common.service.activator*,com.majesco.dcf.common.entity*,com.majesco.dcf.common.service.impl*,com.majesco.dcf.pg.entity*,com.majesco.dcf.pg.service*,com.majesco.dcf.pg.util*,com.majesco.dcf.pg.billdesk.impl*,com.majesco.dcf.receipt.util*</excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Do I need to make any additional changes to make scheduler working? please suggest what is missing.

Comment: is your bundle active? you can check it on `/system/console/bundles` on CQ.

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes, it is in active state

Comment: is the component for `ScheduledPeriodicJob` also active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked as required, here three cases are handled

- with `addJob()` : executes the job every minute
- with `addPeriodicJob()` : executes the job every 3 minutes
- with `fireJobAt()` : executes the job at a specific date (date of deployment + delay of 30 seconds)

  ```
  import java.io.Serializable;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;

  import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
  import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
  import org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.Scheduler;
  import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
  import org.slf4j.Logger;
  import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

  @Component
  public class ScheduledPeriodicJob {

  /** Default log. */
  protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  /** The scheduler for rescheduling jobs. */
  @Reference
  private Scheduler scheduler;


  protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) throws Exception {
      //case 1: with addJob() method: executes the job every minute
              String schedulingExpression = "0 * * * * ?";
              String jobName1 = "case1";
              Map<String, Serializable> config1 = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
              boolean canRunConcurrently = true;
              final Runnable job1 = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                      log.info("\n\nExecuting");
                  }
              };
              try {
                  this.scheduler.addJob(jobName1, job1, config1, schedulingExpression, canRunConcurrently);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  job1.run();
              }

      //case 2: with addPeriodicJob(): executes the job every 3 minutes
              String jobName2 = "case2";
              long period = 180;
              Map<String, Serializable> config2 = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
              final Runnable job2 = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      log.info("\nExecuting 2");
                      log.info("\nExecuting 2");
                      log.info("\nExecuting 2");
                      log.info("\nExecuting 2");
                      log.info("\nExecuting 2");
                      log.info("\nExecuting 2");
                      log.info("\nExecuting 2");
                      log.info("\nExecuting 2");
                  }
              };
              try {
                  this.scheduler.addPeriodicJob(jobName2, job2, config2, period, canRunConcurrently);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  job2.run();
              }

      //case 3: with fireJobAt(): executes the job at a specific date (date of deployment + delay of 30 seconds)
              String jobName3 = "case3";
              final long delay = 30*1000;
              final Date fireDate = new Date();
              fireDate.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() + delay);
              Map<String, Serializable> config3 = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
              final Runnable job3 = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                      log.info("\nExecuting at date: {} with a delay of: {} seconds", fireDate, delay/1000);
                  }
              };
              try {
                  this.scheduler.fireJobAt(jobName3, job3, config3, fireDate);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  job3.run();
              }
  }

  protected void deactivate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
      log.info("Deactivateddbye!");
  }

  }
  ```

Below is `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- P A R E N T P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
        <artifactId>schedule</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->

    <artifactId>schedule-bundle</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>My Project Bundle</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tagic</groupId>
            <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/logger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tagic</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler-2.3.3-R1232965.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- B U I L D D E F I N I T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.adobe.cq.schedule-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <slingUrl>http://${crx.host}:${crx.port}/apps/myproject/install</slingUrl>
                    <usePut>true</usePut>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludePackageNames>
                        *.impl
                    </excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to set `immediate = true`. This starts/activates an component/service automatically with the bundle-start. Otherwise the service is only started, if another (already started) service requests this service (or has a dependency).

In OSGi all services are lazy started, and stopped as soon as nobody needs them. I agree, it could be improved, if the scheduler service would automatically start all services that it would trigger. But that's the way it is.

---

This is a working example.

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
@Service({ Runnable.class, AnotherServiceInterface.class})
@Properties({
   // run every 5 seconds
   @Property(name = "scheduler.period", longValue = 5),
   // no concurrent execution
   @Property(name = "scheduler.concurrent", propertyPrivate = true, boolValue = false)
})
```

Comment: Do I need to add any dependency for `@Properties` annotation, because it's throwing _Properties cannot be resolved to a type_  please guide.

Comment: import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;

Comment: The OSGi annotations have changed in the recent years twice. And you use a very old one. So I'm not sure. But for testing, just remove the scheduler.concurrent. It is not needed. Just the the immediate=true to your code. This should already solve your problem

Comment: tried above way, but it doesn't work. I added different logger. Checked `error.log` and other logs also, but no use.

Comment: Just a question: The bundle itself works? So you have other services in it, that are working and running. The pom.xml does not look so trustworthy.

Comment: this bundle works, i want to make scheduler for one of the existing service from that bundle.